# Firebase storage image not downloading on android (but Works fine on Ubuntu)

Tags: android, kivy, python-3.8, kivymd, buildozer

I am building an kivymd app which requires downloading an image from firebase storage, minimum code is below. app works fine on ubuntu, downloads the image where main.py file is, but when i buildozer android debug deploy run it for android it presses the download button and shows the toast of downloading. nothing in gallery or in the storage of android. No errors in logcat. Please Help

```py
import pyrebase
config={''}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()
image_object=storage.download('ss.jpg','payment_track.jpg')
toast(text='Downloading...')
```

Comment: Well, tell path where the file should land.

Comment: @blackapps how can i do that for android sir

Comment: If you dont know the path then where did you look in storage?

Comment: @blackapps i did os.listdir() it shows the downloaded file in directory of within the apk file..which we cannot see without parsing the apk......is there a way we can change the directory only once to download this jpg file.....please help

Comment: Well if it shows file then tell the path! I asked for that remember?

Comment: @blackapps can you help me with a way to change the download path sir?....because that path cant be declared sir. its inside the context directory.

Comment: You did still not tell used download path.